# List of Numbers - How to Efficiently Find Largest Less Than or Equal to N

Tags: c#, algorithm

Say I have a fixed set of numbers that happens to be sorted:

```
static readonly int[] numbers = new int {
    1, 200, 204, 228, 298, 300, 331, 332, ... 2983
};
```

How would I efficiently find the largest number less than or equal to an arbitrary value.  The function I am trying to create is as follows:

```
public int LessThanOrEqualTo(int n)
{
    // ???
}
```

The simplest way would be to iterate over the set every time.  However, I am looking for a way to make this faster.  I am ok converting this to another format such as an `IDictionary`, but cannot think of a clever way do this offhand.

Comment: Do binary search?

Comment: Note "if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item", thus if not found you get the next larger, and thus you can then move back one index to get the element you desire.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kwds4b1.aspx

Comment: @AaronLS Note that in this case it would be `Array.BinarySearch` not the list version.

Comment: This isn't exactly a binary search, although incorporating binary search is probably a good idea.

Comment: What should happen if someone passes in -1, or any other number less than the smallest number in the array?

Comment: @MattGreer This is *exactly* a binary search, actually.

Comment: @Servy Link edited, not there are several other overloads of that function that may serve the asker better.

Comment: 1) With such a short list, linear scan is pretty fast 2) As an alternative to a list you could use a tree with high fanout. That reduces the number of iterations a bit.

Comment: @CodesInChaos We don't know how many numbers appear between the `...` :D

Comment: @CodesInChaos A binary search on a list/array would actually be faster than a tree-based structure as you get improved memory locality.

Comment: I think @AaronLS is onto something.  `Array.BinarySearch` has the same comment as the `List.BinarySearch`.

Comment: I did some testing a few years back to compare the speed of binary search and linear search in an integer array. I was surprised to find that linear search was faster than `Array.BinarySearch` when the array had fewer than 12 items. After that, binary search was the clear winner. I had expected linear search to be faster for arrays up to perhaps 32 items.

Comment: @Servy, no it's not. Once you find a number that is less than the target, is that the number? There might be a larger number that is still less than the target.

Comment: @MattGreer What are you talking about.  A binary search doesn't just find a number that's less than the target, a binary search will either find the exact value if it exists, and if it doesn't the position in the array that it would belong if it were added.  The item just before that is the highest number less than it, and the number above it is the lowest number larger than it.  That's *exactly* what the OP needs.  It sounds like you don't know what a Binary Search does.  It's worth reading up on if that's the case.

Comment: @Servy so how is that *exactly* a binary search? You use a binary search, but you don't exactly use the results of it, thus it is not *exactly* a binary search, it's an algorithm that incorporates a binary search. Even the accepted answer here says that. If it was exacty a binary search, once you found the element meeting your requirements you'd short circuit the search, which you can't do here.

Comment: @MattGreer There is no circumstances in which, had you written your own algorithm, you could short circuit the results and end more quickly than the `BinarySearch` method.  Also note I didn't say it was exactly the `BinarySearch` method, I said it was exactly a Binary Search, in the abstract programming sense, to which it is.  The specific signature of the method he wants is slightly different than the List or Array implementation, but they are all just different implementations of a binary search in the abstract computer science sense.

Comment: @Servy and a binary search, as any search algorithm, says "yes this item is in the list or it isn't", which is not what's being asked here. You need to use the results of a binary search to determine your answer, not the actual answer of the search itself. You used the word "exactly", which this is clearly not.

Comment: No, a binary search does not produce a boolean result, it's not asking a yes or no question.  It doesn't return a `bool`.  It's finding a particular position; that position can be marked by an index, such as in the case of an array, or it can be marked by a reference to a neighboring node, such as in the case of a graph-based structure.  Returning the node that's just before where the searched item would go is one valid implementation of a binary search (meeting an exact definition).

Comment: @Servy I'm done here. We clearly don't see eye to eye. I still stand that if it was *exactly* a binary search, then simply using a binary search implementation would do the trick. Yet clearly that is not the case.

Comment: @Servy and btw, if you look up most implementations of binary search, they do *not* return the key where they item would be, they return a sentinel value indicating the item was not found. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492840/find-the-largest-value-smaller-than-x-in-a-sorted-array).

> Use Array.BinarySearch. If the input is in the list, it will return the index, and if not then it will return the complement of the index of the first larger value. You just invert the result and subtract one to get the index of the closest smaller value.

Comment: That's not just similar, it's an exact dupe.  You can just vote/flag to close in such cases.

Comment: @Servy There is a really small difference. `<=` vs. `<`.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that. I'm new here. I will from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Binary search would probably be your best option if you don't have control over the list's generation

*note: this is psudocode and it's not intended to cover all edge conditions

```
FindLargestLessThan(int val, int[] arr, int hi, int lo)
{
    if(hi == lo)
    {
        // it's either arr[hi] or the element immediately before that.
    }
    else if(arr[(hi+lo)/2] > val)
    {
        return FindLargestLessThan(val, arr, (hi+lo)/2, lo)
    }
    else if(arr[(hi+lo)/2] < val)
    {
        return FindLargestLessThan(val, arr, hi, (hi+lo)/2)
    }
    else if(arr[(hi+lo)/2] == val)
    {
        //found it
    }
    else
    {
        //oops
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you do differently if you *did* have control over the list's generation?

Comment: @Servy you can do some sort of hashing implimentation

Comment: Not really.  Hashing is for finding exact values, not for values that are "close".  Any time you want to find values that meet some condition other than equality hashing tends to break down in all but the rarest of cases.